# diffusion limit of random walks via master equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, statistical-mechanics

I've seen the derivation of diffusion from random walks using the following calculations:

Master equation of an unbiased random walk is $p(x,t+1) = \frac12 p(x-1,t) + \frac12 p(x+1,t)$

Let $p = p(x,t)$ and subscript denote partial derivative. Taylor expansion of both sides gives
$$ p + p_t + \dots = \frac12 (p - p_x + \frac12 p_{xx} + \dots) + \frac12(p + p_x + \frac12 p_{xx} + \dots)$$
so that ignoring higher order terms and canceling $p$'s,
$$p_t = \frac12 p_{xx} \;\;\;\;\; \text{(diffusion equation).}$$

I know this diffusion equation is the hydrodynamic limit -- the probability density describing the locations of $n$ iid random walks as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and if we scale the space and time somehow. But the derivation above only deals with a single particle. How do we formalize the idea that this is supposed to describe $n$ particles? For one particle, the density is discrete: if $p(x,0) = \delta_{x_0}$ is the initial condition, then $p(x,t)$ has support on discretely many points. I don't see where the jump from discrete to continuous (and where the scaling) comes in.

Comment: I think you will find an answer [here](https://www.ippt.pan.pl/repository/open/o2277.pdf) in what the author of the article calls Kac's approach.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you but I can't access the link - do you have another?

Comment: @JeanMarie oh is it Random Walk, Diffusion and Wave Equation by R Wojnar?

Comment: Can you access to it now (https://www.ippt.pan.pl/repository/open/o2277.pdf) ? It is an article yes by Wojnar.

Comment: @JeanMarie that one doesn't, but I found it on researchgate. I like this derivation but my question still lingers. This derivation is based on the probability distribution of a single particle. Is there a way to see the derivation for 2, or $n$ particles (perhaps from different initial conditions)?

Comment: I am afraid that this too simple modelization based on the fact that at each unit of time step the particle must move eastward of westwards from a unit of length cannot be improved by considering $n$ particles instead of a single one. You have to consider the Kac's model.

Comment: @JeanMarie isn't Kac's model for one particle though? He talks about the probability of a particle being a position $m$ being bernoulli in the possible paths it could have taken